# Memory Leak while creating and copying Images with NSFiIlemanager on iPad App

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfilemanager

I have a memory leak which crashes my App while copying / creating images width NSFileManager.

When i profile my App with "Allocations", everything looks fine. The Allocated Memory Goes up from aprox 1.5 MB to 6 MB during every recoursion and then drops to 1.5MB again.

But the "Real Memory" and "Virtuel Memory" grows to aprox 150MB and then the App crashes.

I receive Memory Warnings Level 1 and 2 before.

here is the function us use:

```
-(void) processCacheItems:(NSMutableArray*) originalFiles
{
    if ( [originalFiles count] == 0 )
    {
        [originalFiles release];
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSString *curFileName = [originalFiles lastObject];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:curFileName];
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

        CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(150,150);
        CGSize previewDestinationSize = CGSizeMake(1440.0, 1440.0);

        UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; // AUTORELEASED

        // create thumb and copy to presentationfiles directory
        UIImage *thumb = [originalImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
                                                             bounds:destinationSize
                                               interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh]; // AUTORELEASED

        // the resizedImageWithContentMode: does not semm to make the problem, because when i skip this and just use the original file the same problem occours

        NSString *thumbPath = [thumbsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:curFileName];
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:thumbPath contents:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumb, 0.9) attributes:NULL];

        // create thumb and copy to presentationfiles directory
        UIImage *previewImage = [originalImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
                                                                    bounds:previewDestinationSize
                                                      interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh]; // AUTORELEASED

        NSString *previewImagePath = [previewsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:curFileName];
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:previewImagePath contents:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(previewImage, 0.9) attributes:NULL];


        // copy copy original to presentationfiles directory
        NSString *originalPath = [originalFilesDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:curFileName];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:originalPath error:NULL];

        [originalFiles removeLastObject];

        [pool drain];

        [self processCacheItems:originalFiles]; // recursion
    }

}
```

Comment: Go to the build settings and enable "Run Static Analyser".

Comment: use instrument tool to find where is memory leaking..

Comment: @iAmitWagh i cant see it in Instruments, using Memory Leaks.. 
In "Allocations" it looks good as well..

Comment: @WTP. I have enabled "Run Static Analyser" What can i see now? and where?

Comment: If you build again it will show blue messages indicating wrong use of memory management, unused variables and more. Just hit Build. If you double click the blue messages Xcode will show blue arrows indicating how to fix it.

Comment: @WTP thanks, but it says "analyzing finished, no issues"

Comment: @Wolfgang are you using any third-party libraries?

Comment: Clean before running the analyser.

Comment: I can't see any obvious leak in your code, but using recursion and releasing the array when it's empty isn't a great way of organising this.  Why don't you just iterate through the array and release it afterwards?  A method name of `processCacheItems:` does not indicate that it will be releasing the argument that you give to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your Hint.

I fond out, that the Problem was not a leak, but the memory Allocation was too big when scaling down Big Images in "resizedImageWithContentMode:" That made the App crash.

I changed the Image scaling to use the Image I/O framework. 
Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This answer is outdated. If you are using ARC, ignore it .

How do you allocate NSFileManager?

I have experienced that allocating it via the `+ defaultManager` method, which is deprecated, produces memory leaks (or Instruments says so, Instruments sometimes reports memory leaks where there are not).

Generally, you should allocate it with `[[NSFileManager alloc] init]` and release when you no longer need it.